# Is there a way to push down and name all NLA strips/tracks the same thing?

Tags: animation, scripting, gltf

GLTF requires all animations per object to be pushed down and for all NLA tracks to have the same name in order for them to work. Obviously, this is not ideal to do by hand...

"Animation
glTF allows multiple animations per file, with animations targeted to particular objects at time of export. To ensure that an animation is included, either (a) make it the active Action on the object, (b) create a single-strip NLA track, or (c) stash the action.

Supported

Only certain types of animation are supported:

Keyframe (translation, rotation, scale)
Shape keys
Armatures / skinning
Animation of other properties, like lights or materials, will be ignored."

Comment: If you only want one animation containing all the active actions, export with "Group by NLA Track" off.

Answer (score 1):

I made a script to handle animations for glb export. If you press join animation for all objects it will create a new nla track with the same name. You can also simply rename your track or even have multiple animations on the same object.

[image]

https://github.com/LorenzWieseke/GovieTools/releases